# Matlab scraping and encoding

Tags: matlab, encoding, web-scraping

I tried to scrape a site with the urlread2 function. After defining headers and everything I got a result that I don't know how to read:

> '      lA®·E÷Òc?£$êoÅð
>   $qàxdï¿»ÅKÞDDõa²n_K?~~ÿùËo¿ûí×¿ÿ{è}|züùý¯o?¿}ÿãYúòåÑïÏËl>ë­·Ïª¯¾<ÆõùºPZ(5\µJc¼KýóWéå¥W9¾ká`5tÁjè8ÕÐq«¡ã
>   wbyG    .......

I tried some decoding with unicode2native and ISO-8859-1. But what I got are numbers from 0 to 255 and I don't know what to do next...

Looking forward your suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the actual source of the site? What does it say? What is the URL in question and what code are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the weird output:

One of the headers is

> Accept-Encoding:  **gzip, deflate, sdch**

Hence the default option is **gzip**. Once I took out this header the result returned in a usual and readable way.